# Symfony2 controller forward method not decoding strings

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to do a forward in Symfony2 that looks like this

```
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_demo', array('query' => "test?foo=bar")));
```

While it does go to the correct route, the query string is encoded in my browser location bar:

```
http://demo.localhost/demo/test%3Ffoo=bar
```

What I expect

```
http://demo.localhost/demo/test?foo=bar
```

Here's my route

```
acme_demo:
    pattern:  /demo/{query}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:demo }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array('query' => "test", "foo" => "bar")` should work on it's own and put foo as a GET parameter automatically as it is not specified in your route rule, it works in the twig templates, haven't tested it tho.